# How to remove duplicate countries from the list in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I use Ruby on Rails 5.2 and Mongoid 7.0

How to remove duplicate countries from the list

```
@badge = @user.places.all

<%= @badge.each do |badge| %>
  <%= badge.country %><p>
<% end %>
```

Now result:

> France Netherlands Spain Netherlands Netherlands Netherlands Indonesia

I need:

> France Netherlands Spain Indonesia

Comment: Please strip down your problem to the bare minimum (pure Ruby, for example). Then test and debug. If your problem persists, please post _all_ the code necessary to reproduce the problem, describing what you already tried to solve the problem. However, if you find the problem yourself, you might want to write your own answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the badges are different but some of them appear to have the same country. Therefore I think you cannot call `unique` on the badges but must call it on the list of different countries:

```
<% @badge.map(&:country).unique.each do |country| %>
  <p><%= country %></p>
<% end %>
```

Depending on your database structure and if you need the whole `@badges` variable in another place there also might be the option to only load a distinct list of countries from the database:

```
@countries = @user.places.distinct.pluck(:country)

<% @countries.each do |country| %>
  <p><%= country %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the first line with: `@badge = @user.places.all.uniq`.

[Reference](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq)

Comment: unless he wants to keep all places in `@badge` in that case `@badge.uniq.each` should works as well